# Test malware files in host machine?

Tags: binary-analysis, malware, dynamic-analysis, virtual-machines, sandbox

To analyze malware files we are using virtual machine and virtual box but some of malware detect the environment and will not do its work properly.

I want to know how to test malware files with out using virtual environment.

Can i use my host system for testing malware files? If i use host machine for malware testing, how to recover it after infection? Is it possible or not, otherwise give me some idea how can i do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

> I want to know how to test malware files with out using virtual
>   environment.

Check out the answers in the following, similar, question:
[Analysing malware in a real environment (non-virtual environment)](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/17045/analysing-malware-in-a-real-environment-non-virtual-environment)

**TL;DR**: Check out [Faronics Depp Freeze](http://www.faronics.com/en-uk/products/deep-freeze) for example.
I recommend reading the answers as a whole.

In addition, read the answers to the following question on Security.SE:
[Can i get 100% protection from virus by using Deep Freeze?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/19988/can-i-get-100-protection-from-virus-by-using-deep-freeze)

---

> Can i use my host system for testing malware files?

This is **highly not recommended**. Unless this is a physical machine dedicated to run malware samples and you have the means to restore the original state of the machine.

---

> some of malware detect the environment and will not do its work
>   properly.

Read about anti-anti evasion techniques and how to harden your virtual amchine against VM-aware malware samples, there are tons of articles online.

For example:
[Making Virtualbox nearly undetectable](http://blog.michaelboman.org/2014/01/making-virtualbox-nearly-undetectable.html)
[Hardening Cuckoo Sandbox against VM aware malware](https://www.reddit.com/r/UIC/comments/1542ms/hardening_cuckoo_sandbox_against_vm_aware_malware/)

Answer (score 1):

Use KVM. Most of the time malwares will try to detect VMWare and Virtualbox based artifacts.